# How to use conditions in gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I'm managing several `pdf` and `graffle` files with git. I want to add `pdf` files to repository only if `graffle` with same filename does not exists, e. g.

only add `foo.pdf` and `bar.graffle` into repository in the directory

```
$ ls
foo.pdf
bar.pdf
bar.graffle
```

If such target can't be completed only with `gitignore`, is there any work arounds exist?

`bar.pdf` can only be generated with `bar.graffle` through several steps in GUI, so I want to keep them on commit.

Comment: Individually add each file which satisfies the condition to your `.gitignore`?

Comment: @tripleee It's the solution i'm using now, but i'm curious about a "perfect" one.

Comment: OmniGraffle has some apple script support. Google for script to convert .graffle to .pdf.

Comment: @alexvasi I found a applescript, but it doesn't work. I'm not good at debugging applescript.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `.gitignore` only exists as a hint to `git` as to which files, directories or file types will be ignored by `git add`.

However, `.gitignore` will not stop any file to be added into repository if you use `git add -f`.

Long story short, `.gitignore` is rather simplistic mechanism that helps to avoid accidentally adding typical junk files (like editor backups, object files, executables, etc.), but it is not sophisticated enough to be capable of what you are asking for - like changing behaviour depending on some external conditions.

You can be careful not to add some files if you don't want them, or add ignored files with `git add -f` and thus overriding existing simple rules.

Alternatively, you can create some script and register it as git macro like `git addc` that will do such advanced filtering.

Comment: A great explanation. But I think it's also necessary to add that ignored files also won't be visible for `git status`. If you want to check ignored files you should use `git status --ignored`.