# gitignore in Eclipse workspace rather than each project

Tags: eclipse, git, egit

Is there a way to have Eclipse (egit plugin) to respect the .gitignore file in the root of the the local repo? Eclipse seems to prefer a .gitignore in each project, I have multiple projects in the repo so it's somewhat cumbersome to manage multiple ignore files.

Thanks

Comment: The .gitignore should be configured per project.

Comment: having 60 gitignore files in my eclipse workspace hardly seems like a good solution (60 projects in the workspace).

Comment: We are talking about vcs after all. If somebody clones one of your project and it doesn't have .gitignore they eventually push something that should be ignored.

Comment: I don't know why someone would clone and build just one of the projects when it has dependencies across multiple other projects? Anyone working on this product would want to take a fair few of the other projects and would certainly want a gitignore file at the root of the workspace

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create global gitgnore file, say in `~/.gitignore`, and then configure git to actually use it:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore
```

After that, all git related tools (including Eclipse) should use global `.gitignore` file.

Note that while EGit does not support all git features, this one is supported: http://wiki.eclipse.org/EGit/FAQ.

Comment: Seems to work. I'm assuming by global we're just talking within the context of the local repository and not every local repo I have on my machine?

Comment: Global really means global - effect of this .gitignore will be added to all git repositories you have on your computer now. This is actually good as far as I am concerned - for example, on Mac it is very helpful to have `.DS_Store` added to such global .gitignore

Comment: It's also bad because I don't want to ignore bin/ in every workspace.

Comment: Remember that .gitignore is [just a hint](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14037355/1734130) which you can override with `git add -f`. Effects of such global gitignore are added to effects of any local gitignore, so you will have to find a way to use what's most convenient for you. For example, `.DS_Store` and `*.bak` should be in global gitignore, and other rules should be set on a case by case basis